# xmltable Oracle error : ORA-00905: Missing keyword

Tags: plsql

I am trying to join data from xml table and schemas from other tables like:

```
 for  przewod in (select prz.id, sr.kod, mat.kod
                  from xmltable (xmlnamespaces(default 'http://xxx/xx/xx-xx/xx/v1'),
                  'xx/xx' passing message.xx
                  columns
                  id varchar(20) path 'id',
                  xxxx varchar(20) path 'xxxx',
                  xx varchar(20) path 'xx') prz
                  left join sr.kod from z.a sr on sr.kod = prz.xxxx 
                  left join mat.kod from z.b mat on mat.kod = prz.xx )
```

but got always **** here:

```
left join sr.kod from z.a sr on sr.kod = prz.xxxx
```

why is that? what I am missing here? Just started with pl/sql and it is bit overwhelming :/ :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how the JOIN syntax works.

```
LEFT JOIN z.a sr ON ( sr.kod = prz.xxxx )
```

where `z` is the schema name, `a` is the table_name and `sr` is the alias.